# Copying files within a Workgroup

Tags: windows, powershell, copying

I have three boxes operating in a Windows Server workgroup within a closed network. (No Domain / No AD)

There are several derivations of the scenario that I'm about to outline, but I'm sure I will be able to retool the solution as and when I need.

Essentially the boxes are:

2 x Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Standard
1 x Windows Server 2000 Standard

I need to be able to schedule the copying/and-or/moving of files from various directories and each of the boxes. Each box has a different username and password for the administrator.

I have PowerShell 2.0 on the two Win2K8 boxes (obviously).

Previously I have used mapped network drives to copy the files, and cmd line batches, but I'd much rather use Powershell if possible (with Shares and/or $ notation). However the Copy-Item cmdlet doesn't seem to be processing the Credential correctly.

Perhaps some Powershell gurus out there might be able to help me.

Essentially I'd like to schedule a PS run of script to push backup files onto my WIn2k box (old fileserver) periodically.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed your code (I like that rhyme) and was more specific about "processing the Credential correctly" regarding error messages, etc.?

Comment: Are there identical user accounts (with the same passwords) on each server?

Answer (score 1):

When operating in Workgroup mode there are a number of Windows Server 2008 default UAC behaviours that may cause you issues - in particular the explicit Administrator account is treated differently (it auto-elevates by default) to members of the Administrator groups on the machines. I'm not aware of any Powershell specific examples of this but these differences certainly affect WMI connections and attempts to map to Administrative shares.